# Deserialize a CSV and determine the datatypes of its columns

Tags: java, csv

I need to deserialize a CSV file and generate a json file that defines the csv schema. To read the csv and get the headers I am using the commons-csv library. The only problem is that I need to include the 'datatype' of each column, and all of the CSV record values are being stored in memory as Strings after I deserialize.

Let's say I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
col1, col2, col3
val1, val2, 3
```

I want my schema to look like this:

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "headerName": "col1",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "headerName": "col2",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "headerName": "col3",
            "type": "Integer"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the best way to try and determine the type of of these values even though they are being stored as Strings? Is there a library out there that already does this? I'd rather not reinvent the wheel in this situation.

I know this isn't really ideal but I have to do it

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if some sample code had been provided.
However, guessing from the sample input, the `column#3` will always contain `Integer` values.

If you want to check whether a `String` is an `Integer`, you may use [StringUtils.isNumeric()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Comment: I should have mentioned, I need to be more precise than just 'is it numeric'. I need to distinguish between doubles, longs, dates, booleans, etc etc... However, I think i've found a solution. I will need to sample a bunch of rows from the CSV and try to guess the type based on the sample.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help out. However, if there is random data in the column I guess random type checking may not help too. You may run into unnecessary exceptions later on.